# TestMain for all tests?

Tags: go

I have a fairly large project with many integration tests sprinkled throughout different packages. I'm using build tags to separate unit, integration and e2e tests.

I need to do some setup before running my integration and e2e tests, so I put a `TestMain` function in a `main_test.go` file in the root directory. It's pretty simple:

```golang
//go:build integration || e2e
// +build integration e2e

package test

import (
  ...
)

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
  if err := setup(); err != nil {
    os.Exit(1)
  }

  exitCode := m.Run()

  if err := tearDown(); err != nil {
    os.Exit(1)
  }

  os.Exit(exitCode)

}

func setup() error {
  // setup stuff here...
  return nil
}

func tearDown() error {
  // tear down stuff here...
  return nil
}
```

However, when I run test:

```sh
$ go test -v --tags=integration ./...

testing: warning: no tests to run
PASS

# all of my subdirectory tests now run and fail...
```

I really don't want to write a `TestMain` in each package that requires it and was hoping I could just get away with one in the root. Is there any solution that you could suggest? Thanks.

The only alternative I can think of is setting up everything outside of code and then running the integration tests. Maybe some shell script that does setup and then calls `$ go test`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `go test ./...` command compiles a test binary for each package in the background and runs them one by one. This is also the reason you get a `cannot use -o flag with multiple packages` error if you attempt to specify an output. This is the reason code in your main package doesn't effect your sub packages.

So the only way to get this to work is to put all your setup logic in sort of "setup" package and call the shared code from all of your sub-packages(still a lot of work, I know).

Answer (score 2):

Trying to avoid code repetition, I used a function that makes the setup/teardown and evaluates a function as a test.

The function should look like this

```
func WithTestSetup(t *testing.T, testFunction func()) {
    // setup code

    testFunction()

    // teardown code
}
```

I use the `t *testing.T` argument to report errors in setup or teardown, but it can be omitted.

Then in your tests you can make:

```
func TestFoo(t *testing.T) {
    WithTestSetup(
        t, func() {
            if err := Foo(); err != nil {
                t.Fatal(err)
            }
        },
    )
}
```

Just call `WithTestSetup` if needed, looks easier for me than add a bunch of `TestMain`s on the project.

Comment: I would recommend a more Go idiomatic pattern where `WithTestSetup` only receives a `*testing.T` object and registers the teardown logic using `t.Cleanup`. This way you don't have the indentation and it's easier to chain multiple test setup functions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'm relatively new to Go, so I appreciate any feedback. I have two questions. How ensure to run the setup code before every test function? The functions passed to `t.Cleanup` runs for every test function?